# How to hide the Group Tree of a Crystal Report in WPF?

Tags: wpf, crystal-reports

I'm using VS2010 and Crystal reports 13.

Is there any way to collapse/hide the group tree box that appears on the left hand side of my generated report? I saw a couple of proposed solutions but none seem to work for me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I finally found a solution that works, by manually finding the side panel and then hiding it:

```
var sidepanel = crystalReportsViewer1.FindName("btnToggleSidePanel") as ToggleButton;
if (sidepanel != null) {
    crystalReportsViewer1.ViewChange += (x, y) => sidepanel.IsChecked = false;
}
```

adding this namespace:

```
using System.Windows.Controls.Primitives;
```

The problem was that the WPF ReportViewer is slightly diferent to the Win Forms one, some properties (such as ToolPanelView and ShowGroupTreeButton) have been removed, I tried many different things but the above was the only that did the trick.

Answer (score 10):

There also is a property on report viewer you can set as follows:

> yourViewer.ToggleSidePanel = Constants.SidePanelKind.None;

I think this is a bit safer in case the Crystal Reports team decides to rename that button.

Comment: Except than the accepted answer, this is the only working solution for the WPF viewer. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

You can change it from the designer by changing the 'ToolPanelView' to 'None' and hide the button by changing 'ShowGroupTreeButton' to 'false'.  Previous versions had a method to explicitly hide the group tree but I believe it's been deprecated in the version you are using.  To change the properties in code behind:

```
crystalreportviewer.ToolPanelView = TooPanelViewType.None;
crystalreportviewer.ShowGroupTreeButton = false;
```

Comment: thanks for the help justin. I saw that solution somewhere else, but for some reason I can not access 'ToolPanelView' or 'ShowGroupTreeButton' properties, intellisense doesn't recognise them and when I try to add them manually i get errors, any idea why? I'm using CR13 btw.

Comment: Are you trying to set them for the report object?  They are properties of the viewer not the report.  I am using CR13 too and the report viewer has both of those properties in this version.

Comment: of course I'm setting them for the viewer man, as I said below the WPF report viewer is different to the Win Forms one, are you using the WPF viewer?

Comment: I was mistaken, sorry missed the WPF detail.  Thanks for posting your solution I upvoted it.

Answer (score 4):

there is a property DisplayGroupTree . and you can avoid the free space by using this code

CrystalReportViewer1.DisplayGroupTree = false;

CrystalReportViewer1.HasToggleGroupTreeButton = false;

Comment: This method is very usefull thnks @Jidheesh

Answer (score 1):

Use the command to hide the panel.

```
CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView = CrystalDecisions.Windows.Forms.ToolPanelViewType.None
```

I ran into the same issue as Crystal Report changes the convention. In older version of the Crystal report would hide the button and not show the panel on the left hand side.
   CrystalReportViewer1.ShowGroupTreeButton = False

Answer (score 0):

```
<Viewer:CrystalReportsViewer  ToggleSidePanel="None"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the following properties in your webpage:

```
- ToolPanelView="None"
- HasToggleGroupTreeButton="false"

<CR:CrystalReportViewer ID="CRViewer" runat="server" HasCrystalLogo="False" ToolPanelView="None" HasToggleGroupTreeButton="false" BestFitPage="True" AutoDataBind="true"  />
```

Group tree panel and its toggle will be hidden. It works well in my environment - ASP.Net 4.0, Crystal Report version 13.0.13

Comment: This does not answer the question since we're talking about WPF, not ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0):

For asp.net

```
    CrystalReportViewer1.ToolPanelView=CrystalDecisions.Web.ToolPanelViewType.None;
```